# Autodesk Forge - Revit - System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have an app on the Autodesk Forge for Revit . During the processing through this app , it connects to  URL on our servers with some parameters

This url is active and we can visit it without any problems through Browser . But through the application when we submit the work item and get the response, we are getting the below error

**[02/04/2021 13:33:06]    at System.Net.WebClient.OpenWrite(Uri address, String method)**

Snippet of the Report that we get from the Report Url in the Response after submitting the workitem is as below ( Some non relevant but proprietary info has been stripped out )

```
[02/04/2021 13:32:36] Running RevitAssemblyResolver....
[02/04/2021 13:32:36] Initializing RevitCoreEngine...
[02/04/2021 13:32:36] Selected Revit\RCE install Path: (from app.config) C:\Revit2019
[02/04/2021 13:32:36] Resolving location of Revit/RevitCoreEngine installation...
[02/04/2021 13:32:36] Running user application....
[02/04/2021 13:32:41] Found an addIn for registration: XXXXX.addin
[02/04/2021 13:32:41] Initializing RCE....
[02/04/2021 13:32:41] Initializing RevitCoreEngine (and possibly running stub installer)...
[02/04/2021 13:32:41] Language not specified, using English as default
[02/04/2021 13:32:44] Initialize and  get RCE: (VersionBuild) 19.0.0.0 (VersionNumber) 2019 (SubVersionNumber) 2019.2
[02/04/2021 13:33:06] System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 
[02/04/2021 13:33:06]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
[02/04/2021 13:33:06]    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
[02/04/2021 13:33:06]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
**[02/04/2021 13:33:06]    at System.Net.WebClient.OpenWrite(Uri address, String method)**
```

The method that is causing the problem is OpenWrite .  One of the parameters is URL at our end and the second parameter is "POST".

Is it some parameter that we have to specify at the time of uploading app on Forge or some parameter at our server end ?  Not a clue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

During the process of work-item running, it does not support to communicate with other server directly. If your plugin needs to get some data from your server, better define it as a activity parameter, then when the work-item starts, it will download the data to the working directory, If your plugin needs to post some data to your server, better do the job in progress or onComplete callback.

This is a blog that describes the related practices in details:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/communicate-servers-inside-design-automation

Comment: Thanks Liang for answer. We ended up zipping the data and specifying that zip as the output file . This way we don't have to send the file during the process of work item running.